# SQL add a counted value into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hey guys so i get the counted value.
I would like to run it as a stored procedure to update another table with the value i get from the counted.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as counted 
FROM [DB]
WHERE Date_Timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR,6,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110))
AND Date_Timestamp <= DATEADD(HOUR,18,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()+1,110))
and trigger_loc = 'x'
```

Comment: Show the other table, sample data before and after.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) as counted 
FROM [DB]
WHERE Date_Timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR,6,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110))
AND Date_Timestamp <= DATEADD(HOUR,18,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()+1,110))
and trigger_loc = 'x' update [DB2] set [info] = counted where line = a`

Comment: i want to take the data from the count i got and update it to another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make this a stored procedure, you could do it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateTableWithCountedValue AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [Table You Want To Update]
    SET [column you want to update] = (SELECT COUNT(*) as counted 
  FROM [DB]
  WHERE Date_Timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR, 6, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) AND            
        Date_Timestamp <= DATEADD(HOUR, 18 + 24, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) AND
        trigger_loc = 'x')
    WHERE [ConditionForRowsThatShouldBeUpdated]
END
```

Then you can call your stored procedure whenever you want like:

```
exec dbo.UpdateTableWithCountedValue
```

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure is not necessary.  I would use a CTE:

```
WITH newdata as (
      SELECT COUNT(*) as counted 
      FROM [DB]
      WHERE Date_Timestamp >= DATEADD(HOUR, 6, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) AND            
            Date_Timestamp <= DATEADD(HOUR, 18 + 24, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) AND
            trigger_loc = 'x'
    )
update toupdate
    set col = counted
    from t toupdate join
         newdata
         on toupdate.?? = newdata.??;
```

This also simplifies the date arithmetic so it doesn't require converting to strings.

It is unclear what row you want to update.  This assumes there is a `join` on some key